# Regex for replacing space with comma-space, except at end of line

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to covert input file content of this:

```
NP_418770.2: 257-296 344-415 503-543 556-592 642-707
YP_026226.4: 741-779 811-890 896-979 1043-1077
```

to this:

```
NP_418770.2: 257-296, 344-415, 503-543, 556-592, 642-707
YP_026226.4: 741-779, 811-890, 896-979, 1043-1077
```

i.e., replace a space with comma and space (excluding newline)

For that, I have tried:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/[^\S\n]+/, /g" input.txt
```

but it gives:

```
NP_418770.2:, 257-296, 344-415, 503-543, 556-592, 642-707
YP_026226.4:, 741-779, 811-890, 896-979, 1043-1077
```

how can I stop the additional  comma which appear after ":" (I want ":" and a single space) without writing another regex?

Thanks

Comment: How about `/42/`?

Comment: (For those confused, the original question title was "What's the perfect regex?" Sorry @simbabque for spoiling your joke).

Comment: not a direct answer, but for this use-case, how about `s/(\d) (\d)/$1, $2/g`?

Comment: do you have any other kind of space like tabs or just single spaces you need to replace on certain condition? that way you can use just a literal space character without worrying about `\S \h \n` etc...

Comment: my favorite for replacing all but some pattern is to use [SKIP](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).... though in this case using `s/^[^:]+:\h+(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+/, /g` seems unnecessary with easy alternatives available

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using regex negative lookbehind. It is basically look if the character before the space is colon (`:`) then it don't match that space.

```
s/(?<!:)[^\S\n]+/, /g
```

Comment: Or `s/(?<!:)\h+/, /g`.

Comment: what does \h+ do here ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @xtreak: `[^\S\n]` is a pattern to match any whitespace but a newline. I suppose OP needs to match any *horizontal* whitespace, so I suggest `\h`.

Comment: Note that this regex contains a negative lookbehind. Not all engines support it, like the default Javascript regex engine.

Answer (score 4):

You can play with the word-boundary to discard the space that follows the colon: `s/\b\h+/, /g`

It can be done with perl:

```
perl -pe's/\b\h+/, /g' file
```

but also with sed:

```
sed -E 's/\b[ \t]+/, /g' file
```

---

Other approach that uses the field separator:

```
perl -F'\b\h+' -ape'BEGIN{$,=", "}' file
```

or do the same with awk:

```
awk -F'\b[ \t]+' -vOFS=', ' '1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close. That should do the trick:

```
s/(\d+-\d+)[^\S\n]+/$1, /g
```

The thing is, I try to look at the parts that will get a comma after them which apply to the pattern of "digits, then a dash, more digits, then a whitespace that's not a newline". The funny thing about it is that I said that "whitespace that's not a newline" part as `[^\S\n]+` which means "not a non-whitespace or a newline" (because `\S` is all that's not `\s` and we want to exclude the newline too). If in any case you have some trailing whitespace, you can trim it with `s/\s+$//` prior to the regex above, just don't forget to add the newline character back after that.

Comment: can be shortened to `'s/\d\K /, /g'`